# Program not working on other PCs or as other users

Tags: vb.net

I have written a small program that prints the contents of the windows clipboard.

The program works fine on my computer as long as I am logged on as myself but if I log on as another user and try to use the program it won't copy the clipboard data to my program. If I install it on other PC`s I have the same problem even if I am logged on as administrator.

Here is the code I am using :

```
Private Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click

    If Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf) Then
        RTBDisplay1.Rtf = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Rtf)
    Else
        RTBDisplay1.Text = "The clipboad does not contain any text"
    End If

    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 1
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 1

    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If

    Clipboard.Clear()

End Sub
```

I have used the published files to setup the program and also used Inno Setup to create a setup program, the program installs properly and runs properly on my computer and other computers but it just won`t get the clipboard data.

I have tried changing the dataformat to text and copying from notepad but even that doesn`t work either.

Comment: Does your else condition work? I mean do you get this in the tool?`RTBDisplay1.Text = "The clipboad does not contain any text"`

Comment: yes this is what is displayed, so it drops straight through to the else statement.

Comment: Can you try like this `RTBDisplay1.Text = Clipboard.GetText`? Just to make sure that this works.

Comment: This works to get the text format from the clipboard as a different user so what would stop this user getting the rich text format from the clipboard.

Comment: You mean the above code works? If so, try your code by copying a formatted text from Microsoft word. `RTBDisplay1.Rtf =  Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf)`

Comment: Ok I just downloaded free clipboard viewer 2.0 and copied the data to the clipboard and noticed that if I am logged on as a local user the data will show Rich text format but if I log on as a domain user(Including Administrator with no restrictions) it wont give me the rich text format.